# Convert Time Stamps to Different Timezone in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this list of times in timezone "-07:00" and I want to convert them to "+05:00".

```
"hours": [
    {
      "from": "11:00",
      "to": "21:00",
      "dayOfWeek": "MONDAY"
    },
    {
      "from": "11:00",
      "to": "21:00",
      "dayOfWeek": "TUESDAY"
    },
    {
      "from": "11:00",
      "to": "21:00",
      "dayOfWeek": "WEDNESDAY"
    },
    {
      "from": "11:00",
      "to": "21:00",
      "dayOfWeek": "THURSDAY"
    },
    {
      "from": "11:00",
      "to": "21:00",
      "dayOfWeek": "FRIDAY"
    }
  ]
```

How to do this efficiently using a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)? I have worked on a method but it's not up to par.

```
function formatDates(hoursList, shopDate, userDate){
    var moment = require('moment');
    var selectedDateText = "";
    var convertedDateList = [];

    for (var x = 0; x < hoursList.length; x++) {
        var fromDate = shopDate.clone();
        var fromMoment = moment(fromDate.format(), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z");
        var fromTime = fromMoment.utcOffset(userDate.utcOffset());
        fromTime.hours(parseInt(hoursList[x].from.split(":")[0]));
        fromTime.minutes(parseInt(hoursList[x].from.split(":")[1]));
        fromTime.seconds(0);
        fromTime.milliseconds(0);
        console.log(fromTime.format());

        var toDate = shopDate.clone();
        var toMoment = moment(toDate.format(), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z");
        var toTime = toMoment.utcOffset(userDate.utcOffset());
        toTime.hours(parseInt(hoursList[x].to.split(":")[0]));
        toTime.minutes(parseInt(hoursList[x].to.split(":")[1]));
        toTime.seconds(0);
        toTime.milliseconds(0);
        console.log(toTime.format());

        var initialDay = {
            "from": "",
            "to": "",
            "dayOfWeek": ""
        };
        initialDay.dayOfWeek = fromTime.format("dddd").toUpperCase();
        initialDay.from = fromTime.format("HH:mm");

        if (toTime.format("DDD") != fromTime.format("DDD")) {
            var secondaryDay = {
                "from": "",
                "to": "",
                "dayOfWeek": ""
            };
            initialDay.to = "24:00";

            secondaryDay.dayOfWeek = toTime.format("dddd").toUpperCase();
            secondaryDay.from = "00:00";
            secondaryDay.to = toTime.format("HH:mm");

            convertedDateList.push(secondaryDay);
        } else {
            initialDay.to = toTime.format("HH:mm");
        }

        convertedDateList.push(initialDay);
    }
    console.log(convertedDateList);
    return selectedDateText;
}
```

Major problem is, some time stamps when converted will be in 2 different days. Hence the initial and secondary day in the code. Ex: When it's some 6 hours and it gets split in two, it should be added as Monday 9PM - 12PM and Tuesday 12AM - 3AM. And this is even trickier when it's an instance where the hours have all 7 days and some days, after conversion will even have hours from 12AM - 3AM and 9PM to 12PM.

How to tackle this properly?

Thanks.

Comment: Yikes! I am sorry you have such messy input, without time zones. Ouch. What a mess. May I ask, what does `dayOfWeek` refer to? The start time or the end time? Are you able to change the input format? (Because that makes your problems go away.)

Comment: @RayToal Basically it's like Open Hours of a shop. "dayOfWeek" represent the day that it's open. Some shops are open on particular days only.

Comment: Got it--so these are local times. Can you just use dayOfWeek to refer to the starting time?

Comment: @RayToal The list of times are for the shop. Which is in a different timezone("-07:00"). I want to convert the list of times in accordance to the client side, which is in "+05:00".

Comment: So all you need to do is add 12 hours, modulo 24, and bump the day if necessary, right? Or do you need something else?

Answer (score 1):

For timezone related Moment has made a module dependent on moment.js - please find the documentation [here](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)

Comment: I don't get the region string. Just the offset value. Ex: "-07:00"